# Stylize Scrollbar (overflow-y: scroll)

Tags: html, css, scroll, scrollbar

I added overflow-y: scroll; to my .HTML CSS attribute which uses the generic Scrollbar, except I can't style is with CSS3 WebKit. I also tried adding height: 101% to the .HTML CSS attribute, but it still used the generic scroller. I need to have the Scrollbar appear at all times, and be able to style it. What can I do to stylize my scrollbar and make it appear on every page, no matter the height? (I have to do this because my theme changes it's container position on pages that the Scrollbar isn't present).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it appear constantly, just add height (sometimes needed) and overflow-y: scroll. Example:

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but my problem is that I want to use a WebKit style for my Scrollbar, but when I use your solution, the Scrollbar sometimes appears on long pages, sometimes not, and sometimes appears on short, no scrolling pages, and sometimes not..